# writing a function for ggplot + dplyr

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr

I have my df like below.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tibble)

df <- tribble(
      ~variables, ~cities, ~values,
      'var1', "C1", 2.5,
      'var1', "C2", 3.5,
      'var1', "C3", 4.9,
      'var2', "C1", 8.5,
      'var2', "C2", 7.3,
      'var2', "C3", 6.1,
      'var3', "C1", 3.1,
      'var3', "C2", 5.2,
      'var3', "C3", 7.8,   
    )
```

I can produce a lollipop plot using ggplot and dplyr like this case:

```
df %>% 
  filter(cities == "C2") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = variables, y = values)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=variables, xend=variables, y=0, yend=values), color="skyblue") +
  geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
  coord_flip()
```

But I want to write this syntax as a function, with city name as its input.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?  Presumably your function will also need to know which dataset to use and which variable to use for the various elements of the plot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I am missing something, you can simply wrap your code in a function:

```
lolly <- function(city_name){
  df %>% 
    filter(cities == city_name) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = variables, y = values)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x=variables, xend=variables, y=0, yend=values), color="skyblue") +
    geom_point( color="blue", size=4, alpha=0.6) +
    coord_flip()
}

lolly("C1")
```

[image]

Or to see all three:

```
cowplot::plot_grid(
  lolly("C1"),
  lolly("C2"),
  lolly("C3"),
  nrow = 3,
  labels = paste0("City = C",1:3))
```

[image]